# Data Plotly QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm new with QGIS and Data Plotly and I have a problem with pie charts feature for Plotly. 
I load a shape in QGIS and I use it with Atlas to display a pie chart depending of the selected area on the shape. 
In my shape I have a table with cities, Zip Code and a percentage. 
I want to display the pie chart with the percentage for the selected city but I don't understand how to do this.

Edit for csk: I downloaded Data Plotly and I need to make a data vis with QGIS. I make a layer for each view and I add a general map and a zoom map in my project. Now I need to display my pie chart for each area I selected. For each area I have in my shape file a colum "CO2 percent" and I need to display this data for each area in my pie chart.
But there are 2 problems: Data Plotly show the percent of the value of my CO2 column on all the values of this column. And not just for example 23 on 100%.
2nd problem is Data Plotly show me in the pie chart all the area around my selected area

I used this tutorial: https://anitagraser.com/author/oneil974/
Some pictures:
**This is my table**
[image: This is my table]
**The rules for the shape**
[image: Rules]
**And results without the pie chart with Data Plotly and after with the pie chart**
[image]
[image]
So as you can see in the Table screen I want to display in my pie chart the CO2 value as a percentage. Example for (97360|Apatou|5) I want 5% on 100% on my pie chart and I want to see only 1 "Nom_com" not the "Nom_com" around.

Comment: Are you making the pie charts with QGIS's built-in "diagrams" feature, or are you somehow running Plotly inside QGIS? Where exactly are you stuck? Have you succeeded in displaying a pie chart, and now you're just trying to display only the pie chart for the current Atlas page? (If you answer my questions please put the answers directly into your question using the [edit] link.)

Comment: Adding screenshots depicting the problem would be a big help.

Comment: added pictures.

Comment: why not using the feature subset in the Layout Composer? You can filter what you want to get on the plot